# Stopping GCD when replacing scene?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know its impossible to stop a GCD action that started, but i wonder what happens when it is trying to execute after i have already replace a view, means that i have a few GCD functions that loading images to scrollView, and sometimes the user wants to replace the scene while they are working, how should i stop  it than ? or shouldn't i ?

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^
                   {
                       NSData *imgdata  = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                       UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:imgdata scale:1];

                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                      {

                                                 [UIView transitionWithView:backView
                                                            duration:0.55f
                                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                                          animations:^
                                           {

                                            backView.image=image;

                                           }
                                           completion:nil];


                                      });
                   });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could switch to `NSOperation` to get the more precise `cancel` mechanism. But it cannot guarantee that it will cancel if the operation is already in progress. As an option you can check if your `backView` still has superview.

---

If you removed a view from superview no animation work occurred but every step of transition lifecycle happens:

```
- (void)testUIViewOffScreen
{
    UIWindow *aWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows][0];
    UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0)];
    aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [aWindow addSubview:aView];

    [aWindow layoutIfNeeded];

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [UIView transitionWithView:aView duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
                NSLog(@"Transition will start now");
                 aView.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0);
             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 NSLog(@"finished: %@", finished ? @"YES" : @"NO");
             }];
        });
    });

    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0]];

    [aView removeFromSuperview];

    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
```

The output:

```
23.941 TestCase[70489:60b] Transition will start now
23.942 TestCase[70489:60b] finished: NO
```

Comment: So just to know , if i was already replaced a view, he will try anyway to perform the task ?

Comment: @Curnelious some tests can be helpful